# What's the preferred way in the Visual Studio designer to add an attribute to a control?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I need to add attributes to certain controls in a Windows Forms project. It needs to look something like this:

C#

```
[Queryable()] private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtName;
[Queryable()] private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker dtpDateOfBirth;
```

VB.NET

```
<Queryable()> Private WithEvents txtName As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
<Queryable()> Private WithEvents dtpDateOfBirth As System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
```

I can go in and edit the designer file to get more-or-less the desired effect, but those designer files sometimes come with the caveat that they are automatically-generated files. I'm worried that the designer might overwrite any changes that I make to the file. That said, is there a way to add attributes to controls using the designer or is there some way that I can add the attributes in a separate file?

Comment: You'll get away with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test it, but I don't think the definition will get overwritten when using the forms designer. Only if you delete and re-add the control. Possibly if you copy a control the copy might not have the attribute on it. I have had to change controls from `private` to `protected` and that worked. I would think attributes would be the same.